# Identifying cookie data type

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is there some library (preferably in javascript) that will classify a cookie value into some sensible data type?

When I look at various cookie values, I see various types such as:

1. plain english
2. numbers (hex, dec)
3. base64
4. some combination of above

It would be even more awesome if in addition to guessing the data-type, the library can also guess the type of encryption, or hashing used.

I remember experimenting with a python library a while ago but that did not seem to guess even simple hashes such as shasum, sha256sum, sha256sum, md5sum etc

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this since all cookies are stored as string values. A workaround can be to classify them into general classes by putting them through [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

- **/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}$/** Signifying that *could* be an Adler-32 or CRC-32 Checksum
- **/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{32}$/** Signifying that *could* be an MD2, MD4, MD5, or Haval Sum
- **/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{64}$/** Signifying that *could* be a SHA-256 Sum
- **/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{96}$/** Signifying that *could* be a SHA-384 Sum
- **/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{128}$/** Signifying that *could* be a SHA-512 Sum
- **/^[^0-9A-Za-z+/]+={0,2}$/** Signifying that *could* be a Base-64 Encode

There's a chance that any one of these could just be regular numbers or plain test too (like "DEADBEEF"). If you're in charge of that data, I would specify the type in another cookie.

In summary, there's just no guarantee, unless you know what to expect.

Comment: Thanks. I mean that would be my last option. However, I was wondering if some library can assign a data-type probabilistically.